# Editing a private field

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next

I have a class defined with a private property which I would like to add new default values to later (working with optional modules).

Normally, I can add them through `Object.assign(class.prototype.modules, obj);`
But this doesn't work as I'm getting the error `Read of private field #modules from an object which did not contain the field`

Code:

```
class Locals {
    static extend(obj) {
        console.log('obj', obj);
        Object.assign(Locals.prototype.modules, obj);
        // Object.assign(Locals.prototype.#modules, obj) //This doesn't work either
    }

    #modules = {};

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Environment: Node.js v12.0.0

Comment: You should create a setter method in order to change the value of a private field

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to create new defaults. Not changing instance values